# How to overlay a bitmap image with text in EaselJs

Tags: createjs

I want to have a text to be overlayed on top of a bitmap that inside an EaselJs canvas.

In my code, the image was loaded using PreloadJS first thing. Then the text was added later after that. Both of them start at x = 0, y = 0 with different widths and heights. Thus in order to display the text, I need to have it on top of the image.

I have a method to display either text or image based on the parameter, i.e DisplayObj. So basically, I have to call DisplayObj(img) followed by DisplayObj(text). However, this will result in the text is displayed behind the image. If I change my code that instead of doing 2 function calls, I just put the logic of displaying the text after the displaying image, call only 1 time and it worked. However, this is not what I want since sometimes, the text and image are not needed to be overlayed each other, thus this approach seems not quite well.

Any suggestions on how to do this with Easel and jQuery?

Below is my function written in Typescript:

```
function DisplayContentObject(c_xml: any): JQueryPromise<any> {
//var deferred: JQueryDeferred<any> = $.Deferred();
//var promise: JQueryPromise<any> = deferred.promise();

if (c_xml.attributes.is_visible.value === "1") {
    if (c_xml.attributes.type.value.toLowerCase().indexOf("text") > -1) {
        let x: number = +c_xml.attributes.content_pos.value.split(",")[0];
        let y: number = +c_xml.attributes.content_pos.value.split(",")[1];
        let width: number = +c_xml.attributes.content_size.value.split(",")[0];
        let height: number = +c_xml.attributes.content_size.value.split(",")[1];
        var text = c_xml.attributes.data.value;
        var textElement = new createjs.Text(text, "16px Times New Roman", "#00F");
        textElement.x = x + 10;
        textElement.y = y + 10;

        textElement.lineWidth = width;
        textElement.maxWidth = width;
        textElement.lineHeight = 20;

        stage.addChild(textElement);
        stage.update();
        displayContentDeffered.resolve();
    }
    if (c_xml.attributes.type.value.toLowerCase().indexOf("audio") > -1) {
        var fe: string = c_xml.attributes.filename.value.split(".")[1].toLowerCase();
        if (fe === "swf") {
        } else if (fe === "mp3") {
            createjs.Sound.stop();
            createjs.Sound.addEventListener("fileload", SoundFileLoaded);
            createjs.Sound.alternateExtensions = ["mp3"];
            createjs.Sound.registerSound({ id: "audio", src: media_path + c_xml.attributes.filename.value });
        }
        displayContentDeffered.resolve();
    }
    if (c_xml.attributes.type.value.toLowerCase().indexOf("visual") > -1) {
        var file: string = c_xml.attributes.filename.value;
        if (file.indexOf("swf") === -1) {
            let _x: number = +c_xml.attributes.content_pos.value.split(",")[0];
            let _y: number = +c_xml.attributes.content_pos.value.split(",")[1];
            let _w: number = +c_xml.attributes.content_size.value.split(",")[0];
            let _h: number = +c_xml.attributes.content_size.value.split(",")[1];
            var manifest = [
                {
                    src: media_path + file,
                    id: "img", x: _x, y: _y, w: _w, h: _h
                }
            ];
            preload = new createjs.LoadQueue(true);
            preload.on("complete", ImageFileLoaded, this);
            preload.loadManifest(manifest);
        } else
            displayContentDeffered.resolve();
    }
} else {
    if (c_xml.attributes.type.value.toLowerCase().indexOf("audio") > -1) {
        var fe: string = c_xml.attributes.filename.value.split(".")[1].toLowerCase();
        if (fe === "swf") {
        } else if (fe === "mp3") {
            createjs.Sound.stop();
            createjs.Sound.addEventListener("fileload", SoundFileLoaded);
            createjs.Sound.alternateExtensions = ["mp3"];
            createjs.Sound.registerSound({ id: "audio", src: media_path + c_xml.attributes.filename.value });
        }
    }
    displayContentDeffered.resolve();
}   

return displayContentPromise;
}
```

The function takes an XMLObject that contains information it should be display. This XMLObject could contains text info or image url. This function is called within a loop.

So in general:

- I have a list of object to be display. Let say **contents = [a, b, c]**. With **a** is sound, **b** is an image, and **c** is a text.
- Within a loop, iterate the contents object and display each object using DisplayObj function.

The problem occurs at b where I am using PreloadJS to load an image and handle that loading logic in an OnComplete event. As I figure this out, the OnComplete does not completed until we are done with **c**. Thus in this case, the loading sequence would be **a** - **c** - **b**, hence the text is underneath the image. I am still trying by using jQuery Deffered but have no success so far.

Comment: We need to see your `DisplayObj` function to help.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have identified your race condition. There are a couple things you could do.

1. Create a placeholder `Container` and add that to the stage immediately. Then, when the preloader is complete, add the image to that container rather than the stage and you will have the proper layering.
2. Preload all your images before ever parsing out your XML so that they are already available in memory to be added.